# Using RegEx to match patterns in parameters

Tags: python, regex

I would like to pass an IP address as a parameter to a Python script and use regex to check the format of the IP Address supplied, but I am receiving an error when trying to run the script.

The script looks like:

```
from sys import argv

import re

script, ip_address, client_name, printer_model, hostname, mac_address = argv

ip_check=re.compile("^(10)\.(0)\.[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]\.[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]$") 

if ip_check.match(ip_address)

else     return "Invalid IP address" 

endif
```

Everytime I try running the script, I receive :

```
if ip_check.match(ip_address)
                             ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any idea of what's going on? do I need to convert `ip_address` to raw data before it can be analysed using RegEx?

Comment: you are missing `:` after if , `if ip_check.match(ip_address):`

Comment: Also `endif` isn't used in Python. Please read an introductory tutorial.

Comment: Ugh, can't believe I missed those colons. I fell into the habit of including endif after working with Django for the past few weeks. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from sys import argv

import re

script, ip_address, client_name, printer_model, hostname, mac_address = argv

ip_check=re.compile(r"^(10)\.(0)\.[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]\.[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]$") 

if ip_check.match(ip_address):

    continue

else:
     return "Invalid IP address"
```

Try this.Use `r` mode to create a pattern and `:` to use `if` and `else`.